# How to format calendar in moment js

Tags: date, momentjs, date-format, date-formatting

I am trying to implement the momentjs calendar to show the date passed time as follow

```
moment("2016-11-13").calendar(moment("2016-11-13"),{
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd MMM DD',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
    sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

but my requirement is when there is days diff less than 7 days then it should show the day diff not **"Last Monday"**

please correct the format for nextDay, nextWeek, lastDay, lastWeek so that its show the days diff like **1 day ago**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function getdateFormated (date){
    var otherDates = moment(date).fromNow();
    var calback= function () {
       return '['+otherDates+']';
    }
    return moment(date).calendar(null,{
       sameDay: '[Today]',
       nextDay:calback,
       nextWeek: calback,
       lastDay: calback,
       lastWeek: calback,
       sameElse: 'MMM DD, YYYY'
   });
}
```